# Removing labels created by a function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a function that produces labels and uses .place() to put them onto the window. Although later in my program I wish to remove these labels. how would I use the  .place_forget() to hide all of the labels? As I have attempted to call the .place_forget() however only one of the labels is removed. And there are several labels of this kind.

Here is the function that produces the labels:

```
def playerTab(team, name, pos, pts, reb, ast, stl, blk, to, y):
    global playerTeam, playerName, playerPosition, playerPoints, playerRebounds, playerAssists, playerSteals, playerBlocks, playerTurnovers
    #Print the team
    playerTeam = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = team)
    playerTeam.config(height = 1, width = 13)
    playerTeam.place(x=20,y=y)
    #Print the name
    playerName = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = name)
    playerName.config(height = 1, width = 25)
    playerName.place(x=119,y=y)
    #Print the players position
    playerPosition = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = pos)
    playerPosition.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    playerPosition.place(x=302,y=y)
    #Print the players average points
    playerPoints = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = pts)
    playerPoints.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    playerPoints.place(x=338,y=y)
    #Print the players average rebounds
    playerrebounds = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = reb)
    playerrebounds.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    playerrebounds.place(x=374,y=y)
    playerAssists = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = ast)
    playerAssists.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    playerAssists.place(x=410,y=y)
    playerSteals = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = stl)
    playerSteals.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    playerSteals.place(x=446,y=y)
    playerBlocks = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = blk)
    playerBlocks.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    playerBlocks.place(x=482,y=y)
    playerTurnovers = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = to)
    playerTurnovers.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    playerTurnovers.place(x=518,y=y)
```

The code is pretty repetitive but that is not a problem for me at this stage. Although I would also welcome ways of making this more efficient.
This function then uses the previous to produce many labels:

```
def sortByPoints():
    foundPlayers = []
    with open ('PlayerList.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            foundPlayers.append((int(row['Average PTS']), int(row['PlayerCode'])))
    sortedPlayers = sorted(foundPlayers, reverse=True)
    print(sortedPlayers)
    for i in range(len(sortedPlayers)):
        with open ('PlayerList.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                if row['PlayerCode'] == str(sortedPlayers[i][1]):
                    print(sortedPlayers[i][1])
                    playerTab(row['Team'], (row['First Name'] + row['Last Name']), row['Position'], row['Average PTS'], row['Average REB'], row['Average AST'], row['Average STL'], row['Average BLK'], row['Average TO'], (120 + (i * 25)))
```

How would I then hide all of the labels produced. Or is it not possible to do with the approach that I have made?
I am using python 3.4

Comment: If you tried calling `.place_forget()` and only one Label was removed, why not try making a loop to cycle through all the Labels, and remove them one-at-a-time? like in the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm): `for w in self.__pages:
        w.place_forget()`

Comment: yu have to remember all label on list and then you have access to all labels and you can remove them - one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you :

```
from tkinter import *
gui=Tk()
def label():
    global l1,l2,l3,l4
    l1 = Label(gui,text='hi')
    l1.place(x=10,y=10)
    l2 = Label(gui,text='hi2')
    l2.place(x=30,y=10)
    l3 = Label(gui,text='hi3')
    l3.place(x=50,y=10)
    l4 = Label(gui,text='hi4')
    l4.place(x=70,y=10)
def remove_label():
    l1.place_forget()
    l2.place_forget()
    l3.place_forget()
    l4.place_forget()
    print('All cleared!')
b = Button(gui,text='place label',command=label)
b.place(x=10,y=50)
h = Button(gui,text='remove label',command=remove_label)
h.place(x=10,y=100)
gui.mainloop()
```